# "Can't visit this page" error when trying to access Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Google tech support are unable to help me because technically the problem is associated with a personal account.

I often write scripts which are linked to spreadsheets in Google Sheets for my clients. Usually, they make a copy of the spreadsheet on their own Google Drive when I am finished, and they can then continue to use the scripts I've written.

Recently I have 'transferred ownership' of a Google Sheet to a client. I am still able to edit the sheet and scripts file as a collaborator. However, when they try to access the scripts either by using the menu (Tools > Script Editor) or by navigating directly yo script.google.com, they get an unusual error message which reads...

***Can't visit this page***

*It's not available for your account*

Their Google account is a personal one, and it is only a week or two old.

Do I need to instruct them to enable scripts for Google Sheets somewhere? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I find that the easiest way to transfer ownership of a script is through a shared drive where both parties have full access.  In most cases when I do it I'm both parties since I usually log on to their account for them make the transfer and then let them change the password and they're now owner of a new script.  You can still make edits to the script but you can't deploy it as a webapp unless you enter through their account.  So it's much more convenient with two business accounts where you can have access to their domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

My client had registered their account with their company's birth date instead of a real human's birth date. As such, they were under 13 years old which in the UK means Google restricted their account as if they were a child.