# Can not grant access to run scripts from kid account in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a fun spreadsheet to exercise basic math for my kids, but when they are logged on their **kid account**, they **can not run** any **script**s (no fancy script, just copy-paste macro). After s**cript authorization** request they got **error 403**.

```
Chyba 403: access_denied
Podrobnosti požadavku
access_type=offline
login_hint=hanzalek.ben@gmail.com
o2v=1
hl=cs
response_type=none gsession
redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/oauthcallback
state=14621511234839642112
client_id=433541798399-h1ncj2ckkapf2gkcoo59mjv46kem0c88@developer.gserviceaccount.com
display=page
prompt=consent
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.cu
```

When I access the spreadsheet from another adult account everything runs.

link to the spreadsheet (you may copy it and use it for your kids if you wish :):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jy1hHgyCkkIJv26attxikKpJlYb_hjWXTauXMjVyn8E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*It appears that there is a restriction for Kid/Child accounts where Apps Script it not available. As long as your children have restricted accounts, there is nothing you can do about this.*

#### More Information:

I did some testing and was able to reproduce the behaviour. These are the results of my tests:

- If the account is a child account, the `403: access_denied` error is received when trying to run a script from a Spreadsheet.
- If the account is a child account, even if they create a new Sheet themself, **they do not have access** ***at all*** **to the script editor**. This heavily implies that child accounts do not have any Apps Script permissions/abilities at all.
- If the account is not a child account, but the account *is* set up to be supervised in the family group at https://families.google.com/families, they can both run the script written by another account, *and* they have access the Script editor.

After searching the Family Link settings for the kid account, I was not able to find any setting which allows this to be turned on. I did some searching and I wasn't able to find any specific documentation either from [searching on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+%22kids%22+apps+script+403) or on [Google Help](https://support.google.com/search?q=kids+apps+script+403).

I did however find a couple of other Stack Overflow questions in which people have had the same error, and this was also the result of their findings, which I have included below.

#### Google Issue Tracker:

As there doesn't seem to be anywhere that publically mentions this specific Apps Script restriction, I suggest that you file a bug on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) for this, in the linked Apps Script component. They might be able to give you more insight into this behaviour.

In the mean time, it appears the only workaround for this is to have the users of the kids accounts use non-kids accounts while using these Spreadsheets, or maybe looking into embedding the Spreadsheet in a web app and have the scripts execute as you rather than the currently logged-in user. More infor about this can be read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

#### Relevant Questions:

- [New Google Account not able to access script.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414932/)
- [“Can't visit this page” error when trying to access Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880013)

#### References:

- [Your family on Google](https://families.google.com/families)
- [google "kids" apps script 403 - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+%22kids%22+apps+script+403)
- [Search results for kids apps script 403 - Google Help](https://support.google.com/search?q=kids+apps+script+403)
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)
- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)